# how do I count results in API v4

Tags: api

experimenting with refactoring some old code and figured I would experiment with apiv4. 
the first hurdle was figuring out how to use the ArrayObject that is returned.

in apiv3, for example I would look at the count value in the array. 
in apiv4 there is no such value.

my api v3 call looks like this

```
  $result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'return' => array("custom_90", "custom_91", "custom_85", "custom_88", "custom_143"),
    'id' => $alum_cid,
    'custom_143' => $sal['id'],
     ));   
  if ($result['count'] != 0) {
    do things
  }
```

my apiv4 call looks like this

```
$results = \Civi\Api4\Contact::get()
  ->setSelect([
    'Employment_History.Salary_Yearly_', 
    'Employment_History.Currency', 
    'Employment_History.Employer', 
    'Employment_History.End_Date', 
    'Employment_History.relationshipID'
  ])
  ->addWhere('id', '=', $alum_cid)
  ->addWhere('Employment_History.relationshipID', '=', $sal['id'])
  ->setLimit(25)
  ->execute();
```

how do I get the count of the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way the api works now, the thing returned is an ArrayObject which you can call functions on, one of those is count()

so just count the results; and then loop over them as you would if it was a normal array

```
  if (count($results) != 0) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {
      do things
    } 

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v4/usage/ where it says:

- $result->count(): get the number of fetched (if LIMIT used) or
  matching results (if row_count included in select).
- From CiviCRM
  5.50+ $result->countFetched(): get the number of fetched results. If you used LIMIT this won't exceed that number (but could be less).
- From CiviCRM 5.50+ $result->countMatched(): get the total number of
  matching results. If you only fetched a subset (with LIMIT) you are
  required to add row_count to the select clause.